# Solve the the given equation: $\sqrt{3x^2+x+5} = x-3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

We have to find the number of solution for the given equation:
$$\sqrt{3x^2+x+5} = x-3.$$
There are two solution one is

By using graph we get one solution

[image: by using graph]

By squaring both sides we get no solution

[image: by squaring both sides]

I want to know which solution is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The given equation is equivalent to the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
3x^2+x+5=(x-3)^2\\
x-3\ge 0
\end{cases}
$$

---

Note that the system has no solutions because the roots of the second degree equations :
$$
x=\frac{-7\pm\sqrt{79}}{4}
$$
are less than $3$.

And this is in accord with the fact that the graphs of the two functions
$$
y=\sqrt{3x^2+x+5} \qquad y=x-3
$$
have no common points (in your graph you  have the wrong function $x=3$).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

we have $$\sqrt{3x^2+x+5}=x-3$$ it must be $$x\geq 3$$ and after squaring we get
$$3x^2+x+5=x^2-6x+9$$ this is equivalent to $$2x^2+7x-4=0$$ solving this quadratic equation we obtain
$$x_{1,2}=-\frac{7}{4}\pm\sqrt{\frac{49}{16}+\frac{32}{16}}$$
Can you finish this?

Comment: i want to know that why are the graphs having intersection point when there is no value of x which can satisfy this equation

Comment: i have got soln for x it is -4 and 1/2

Comment: if the given equation hasd no real solution then the two graphs also have no intersection points

Comment: the quations have real roots but the value of x i.e -4 and 1/2 do not satisfy x-3>0

Comment: it must be $$x-3\ge 0$$  since the square root is non negative

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: please see the pictures which i have uploaded of my solution

Comment: @SuryanshPratapSingh You've plotted the wrong graph. You've found the intersection of x=3 and $y=\sqrt{3x^2+x+5}$ which is irrelevant. The solution is the intersection of $y=\sqrt{3x^2+x+5}$ and $y=x-3$

Comment: oh yeah... Thanks @CompulsiveMathurbator

Comment: @SuryanshPratapSingh: I've added something to my answer. I hope it's useful :)

Answer (score -1):

x=-4
3*16-4+5=49
(-3-4)(-3-4)=49
So this equation was wrong first place.